# NodeJS res.write doesn't work console works

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use Nodejs to create a REST JSON but when I try to write, it gives me error can anyone help?

```
var oracle = require ( 'oracle' ) ;
var http = require ( 'http' ) ;
var url = require ('url');
var port = 80 ;
var testarray = []; 

var cnnString = {
   hostname        : 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
   port            : xxxxx,
   database        : 'xxxxxxxxxx.com' ,
   user            : 'xxxxx' ,
   password        : 'xxxxxx'
} ;


oracle.connect ( cnnString, countrylist ) ;


function countrylist( err, connection ) {

   var reader = connection.reader("select distinct company_code, company_name from mbl_employee_v order by company_code", []);

function doRead(cb) {
reader.nextRow(function(err, row) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    if (row) {
        // do something with row

        testarray.push(JSON.stringify(row));

        return doRead(cb)
    } else {
        // we are done
        return cb();
    }
})
}

doRead(function(err) {
if (err) throw err; // or log it
console.log("all records processed");
 // console.log(testarray);
});
}



var app  = http.createServer ( cb ) ;
app.listen ( port , function () {
console.log ( 'Http server listening at port : ' + port ) ;
} ) ;

function cb ( req, res ) {  
var QueryVal = url.parse(req.url,true);
res.writeHead ( 200 , { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' } ) ;

switch ( QueryVal.pathname ) {
    case '/' :
        res.write ( "Hello, World" ) ;
        break ;
    case '/about' :

console.log(testarray); 
res.write (testarray) ;

        break ;


    case '/product' :
    res.write ( 'product' ) ;

        break ;         
    default :
        res.write ( 'unknow' ) ;
        break ;
}

res.end ( '' ) ;
} ;
```

here my console.log shows the data, but the res.write gives me error

> http.js:851
>        throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
>             ^ TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
>
> - at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:851:11)
> - at Server.cb(/opt/Nodejs/ex05-readData01.js:65:7)
> - at Server.emit(events.js:98:17)
> - at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
> - at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete]    (http.js:121:23)
> - at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
> - at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)

Comment: do `res.write(JSON.stringify(testArray))` and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
res.write(JSON.stringify(testArray));
```

instead of

```
res.write(testArray);
```

because `write` function takes a String or Buffer as argument, and you are passing an array.